# Excel File Saved in Auto Recovery Please Help

Tags: macbook-pro

I have been working on an Excel document for 6 hours and it has saved in an auto recovery file that I cannot access.

I have reassured that I need to go to finder and select go. However I have a macbook pro and there is no go option in Finder.

Please help

Comment: Go menu shows in Menu bar between View and Window. Mention your OS version and Office Version, someone will be able to help you. Also check this http://superuser.com/a/558407/270195

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 2011, do this:

- Go to the **Finder**, and press **Alt** (or **Option**) while selecting **Go** from the menu at the top
- This will make the **Library** folder visible (*if you don’t press **Alt** you won’t see it and you have to keep **Alt** pressed or it will vanish*)
- Next go to the following folders: `Application Support > Microsoft > Office > Office 2011 AutoRecovery`

When you see the Office 2011 in this view you will be able to locate your file.
[image]